# coffeescript chaining with no parameters?

Tags: methods, coffeescript, chaining, parentheses

Hi I'm wondering if its possible to omit empty parenthesis when chaining in coffeescript.

for example

```
myFunction = -> [...]
chain1     = -> [...]
chain2     = -> [...]  
myFunction().chain1().chain2()
```

to instead

```
myFunction.chain1.chain2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer: no, you can't.

That exact syntax will not work in CoffeeScript. You can only chain methods that have at least one argument, so something like this could work:

```
myFunction arg1
  .chain1 arg2
  .chain2 arg3
```

For jQuery, for example, you can do stuff like:

```
$ ->
  $ '#foo'
    .and '.bar'
    .click ->
      alert 'awesome!'
```

This is because, unlike in Ruby, where referencing a name without a leading '@' or '::' implies a method or a local variable, in CoffeeScript, `myFunction` is an expression that returns the function itself. Thus, `myFunction.chain1` and `myFunction().chain1` can both be valid and mean different things.

Note however, that the `new` keyword implies a function call, so if `myFunction` is an (oddly named) constructor, you could write `(new myFunction).chain1`, but that is again different as `.chain1` would be the property of the prototype.

Moreover, if you are the author of the library in question, you could use [getters/setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) to simulate that behaviour in plain JavaScript, but I would highly discourage that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! good info here. I was looking into various ways of executing methods with no parameters. The closest I got was the `do` call in coffeescript and thought about having `myFunction = do [...]` and then I'll be able to call myFunction without params